# Establish Discord connection in flutter doesnt work

Tags: flutter, discord

I'm currently trying to make a website that reads and displays data from discord. This should be realised in Flutter. I have chosen the library [nyxx](https://pub.dev/packages/nyxx) to create the discord connection.

I have the problem that as soon as I want to establish the Discord bot client connection in a widget or the main function, the page/application no longer loads (regardless of whether the widget is loaded or not). How can I fix this? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

The Code I  have to test the connection in The Main Page:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<bool> isSelected = [false, true, true, true, true];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDiscord();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  }

Future<void> initDiscord() async {
    final client = await Nyxx.connectGateway(
      Secrets.DiscordToken,
      GatewayIntents.allUnprivileged,
      options: GatewayClientOptions(plugins: [logging, cliIntegration]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that the discord Api blocks calls from web.